# Memory size of the new allocated int in c++, Is there a different and better way to see it?

Tags: c++, memory, size, allocation

In this program I am trying to find out how much memory is allocated for my pointer. I can see it in this way that it should be 1 gibibyte which is = 1 073 741 824 bytes. My problem is that the only way I can get this thru is by taking the size of int which is 4 and multiplying by that const number. Is there a different way?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <new>

int main(){

    const int gib = 268435256; //Created a constant int so I could allocate 1 
                           //Gib memory
    int *ptr = new int [gib];

    std::cout << sizeof (int)*gib << std::endl;
    std::cout << *ptr << std::endl;
    std::cout << ptr << std::endl;

    try {
    }catch (std::bad_alloc e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    delete[] ptr;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes. Use `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: There is no way in standard C++, given just a pointer (like `ptr` in your example), to obtain the size of what that pointer points at.   You need to record the size separately.   Or, better yet, don't use pointers or dynamic memory allocation directly.   Use a standard container, such as `std::vector<int>`, which does keep track of the number of elements it contains.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no way. The compiler internally adds information about how much memory was allocated and how many elements were created by `new[]`, because otherwise it couldn't perform `delete[]` correctly. However, there is no portable way in C++ to get that information and use it directly.

So you have to store the size separately while you still know it.

Actually, you don't, because `std::vector` does it for you:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <new>

int main() {

    const int gib = 268435256;

    try {
        std::vector<int> v(gib);
        std::cout << (v.capacity() * sizeof(int)) << '\n';
    } catch (std::bad_alloc const& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
    }
}
```

You should practically never use `new[]`. Use `std::vector`.

---

Note that I've used `capacity` and not `size`, because `size` tells you how many items the vector represents, and that number can be smaller than the number of elements supported by the vector's currently allocated memory.

There is also no way to avoid the `sizeof`, because the size of an `int` can vary among implementations. But that's not a problem, either, because a `std::vector` cannot lose its type information, so you always know how big one element is.

You wouldn't need the multiplication if it was a `std::vector<char>`, a `std::vector<unsigned char>` or a `std::vector<signed char>`, because those three character types' `sizeof` is guaranteed to be 1.

Comment: Thank you very much! Great explanation, the reason i was trying to do that its because i am doing a lab from University, am in the first year of computer science.

I dont really need to check the size of what the pointer is looking too... I was just wondering if one day i needed.

Comment: Just a question does this creates the amount of elements or just a size of an element?

Comment: @AllamoOlsson: `sizeof(int)` is the size of one `int`, `capacity` returns the number of `int`s which fit into the vector's allocated memory.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to retrieve the amount of allocated memory from the pointer. Lets forget for a moment that standard containers (and smart pointers) exist, then you could use a struct that encapsulates the pointer and the size. The most simple dynamic array I can imagine is this:

```
template <typename T>
struct my_dynamic_array {
        size_t capacity;
        T* data;
        my_dynamic_array(size_t capacity) : capacity(capacity),data(new T[capacity]) {}
        ~my_dynamic_array() { delete[] data; }
        const T& operator[](int i) const { return data[i];}
        T& operator[](int i) { return data[i];}
};
```

Note that his is just a basic example for the sake of demonstration, eg you shouldnt copy instances of this struct or bad things will happen. However, it can be used like this:

```
my_dynamic_array<int> x(5);
x[3] = 1;
std::cout << x[3];
```

ie no pointers and no manual memory allocation in the code using the array, which is a good thing. Actually, this alone is already a big deal, because now you can make use of RAII and cannot forget to delete the memory.

Next you may want to resize your array, which requires just a bit more boilerplate (again: take it with a grain of salt!):

```
template <typename T>
struct my_dynamically_sized_array : my_dynamic_array<T> {
        size_t size;
        my_dynamically_sized_array(size_t size, size_t capacity) : 
            my_dynamic_array<T>(capacity),size(size) {}
        void push(const T& t) {
            my_dynamic_array<T>::data[size] = t;
            ++size;
        }
};
```

It can be used like this:

```
my_dynamically_sized_array<int> y(0,3);
y.push(3);
std::cout << y[0];
```

Of course the memory would need to be reallocated when the size grows bigger than the capacity and many more things would be required to make this wrapper really functional (eg being able to copy would be nice).

The bottom line is: **Dont do any of this!** To write a good full-blown container class much more than I can outline here is required and most of that is boiler-plate that doesnt really add value to your code base, because `std::vector` already is a thin wrapper around dynamically allocated memory that offers you all you need while not imposing overhead for stuff you dont use.

Comment: not sure if this adds anything useful, i was just in the mood to convince myself once again how awesome standard containers are :P